# How to access and set the API Gateway "Integration response" options through node?

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway

Amazon's API Gateway has some options for its API calls.  One of these options is Content handling.  I need to write a Node script that changes that option to be "Convert to test (if needed)."  The problem I'm running into is figuring out what libraries to use to access it.  Which library should I use?

I've searched around and all of the libraries I could find were for creating new APIs or just for calling GET or POST methods on them.

Comment: [`putIntegrationResponse`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#updateIntegrationResponse-property) is available in the Javascript aws-sdk if you are asking about updating the Integration response on a request method of an API resource. Otherwise, may I ask where in the API Gateway is __"Content handling"__ set? Can you provide some reference?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  I must've missed that one when I was reading the documentation.